# Bash Shell Programming Store Variables from Text File into Arrays

Tags: linux, arrays, shell, unix, ubuntu

My program should be able to work this way.

Below is the content of the text file named BookDB.txt
The individual are separated by colons(:) and every line in the text file should serve as a set of information and are in the order as stated below.

Title:Author:Price:QtyAvailable:QtySold

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
```

I actually intend to
1) Read the file line by line and store it in an array
2) Display it

However I have no idea on how to even start the first one.
From doing research online, below are the codes which I have written up till now.

```
#!/bin/bash

function fnReadFile()
{
while read inputline
do
 bTitle="$(echo $inputline | cut -d: -f1)"
 bAuthor="$(echo $inputline | cut -d: -f2)"
 bPrice="$(echo $inputline | cut -d: -f3)"
 bQtyAvail="$(echo $inputline | cut -d: -f4)"
 bQtySold="$(echo $inputline | cut -d: -f5)"
 bookArray[Count]=('$bTitle', '$bAuthor', '$bPrice', '$bQtyAvail', '$bQtySold')
Count = Count + 1
done
}

function fnInventorySummaryReport()
{
fnReadFile
echo "Title                  Author           Price          Qty Avail.      Qty Sold      Total Sales"
for t in "${bookArray[@]}"
do
echo $t
done
echo "Done!"
}

if ! [ -f BookDB.txt ] ; then #check existance of bookdb file, create the file if not exist else continue
touch BookDB.txt
fi

"HERE IT WILL THEN BE THE MENU AND CALLING OF THE FUNCTION"
```

Thanks to those in advance who helped!

Comment: there are errors to this chunk of code which I have just posted.

Comment: What errors? If you add them to the question it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: line 12: bookArray[Count]: cannot assign list to array member

Comment: error occurs in this line >  bookArray[Count]=('$bTitle', '$bAuthor', '$bPrice', '$bQtyAvail', '$bQtySold')

Comment: bash does not have multi-dimensional arrays. If that's what you really, really want, use a language with more flexible data structures, such as Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your goal here seems to be clear, how about using `awk` as an alternative to using `bash` arrays? Often using the right tool for the job makes things a lot easier!

The following `awk` script should get you something like what you want:

```
# This will print your headers, formatted the way you had above, but without
# the need for explicit spaces.
BEGIN {
    printf "%-22s %-16s %-14s %-15s %-13s %s\n", "Title", "Author", "Price",
    "Qty Avail.", "Qty Sold", "Total Sales"
}

# This is described below, and runs for every record (line) of input
{
    printf "%-22s %-16s %-14.2f %-15d %-13d %0.2f\n",
    substr($1, 1, 22), substr($2, 1, 16), $3, $4, $5, ($3 * $5)
}
```

The second section of code (between curly braces) runs for every line of input. `printf` is for formatted output, and uses the given format string to print out each field, denoted by `$1`, `$2`, etc. In `awk`, these variables are used to access the fields of your record (line, in this case). `substr()` is used to truncate the output, as shown below, but can easily be removed if you don't mind the fields not lining up. I assumed "Total Sales" was supposed to be Price multiplied by Qty Sold, but you can update that easily as well.

Then, you save this file in `books.awk` invoke this script like so:

```
$ awk -F: -f books.awk books
Title                  Author           Price          Qty Avail.      Qty Sold      Total Sales
Harry Potter - The Hal J.K Rowling      40.30          10              50            2015.00
The little Red Riding  Dan Lin          40.80          20              10            408.00
Harry Potter - The Pho J.K Rowling      50.00          30              20            1000.00
Harry Potter - The Dea Dan Lin          55.00          33              790           43450.00
Little Prince          The Prince       15.00          188             9             135.00
Lord of The Ring       Johnny Dept      56.80          100             38            2158.40
```

The `-F:` tells `awk` that the fields are separated by colon (`:`), and `-f books.awk` tells `awk` what script to run. Your data is held in `books`.

Not exactly what you were asking for, but just pointing you toward a (IMO) better tool for this kind of job! `awk` can be intimidating at first, but it's amazing for jobs that work on records like this!

Comment: hi Dan Fego, so do I actually need to replace any of my codes with the ones you mentioned above? Sorry that this is my first time and I am quite unfamiliar and not used to the syntax of shell prog.

Comment: Hi Dan Fego, apparently I have tried to play around with my codes. but still it came up with errors.

Comment: apparently I have tried to play around with my codes. but still it came up with errors.

I incorporated your codes into my function which should be activated if user inputs the choice from a menu.

Below will be my function

`function(my function)
{
BEGIN
 {
 printf "%-22s %-16s %-14s %-15s %-13s %s\n", "Title", "Author", "Price",
    "Qty Avail.", "Qty Sold", "Total Sales"
 }

{
    printf "%-22s %-16s %-14.2f %-15d %-13d %0.2f\n", substring=${$1:1:22}, 
substring{$2:1:16}, $3, $4, $5, {$3 * $5}
}

awk -F: -f BookDB.awk BookDB.txt
}`
when i tried to run it it says bad substitution.

Comment: (the above.) The error stated : bad substitution along in this part of the code. >> substring=${$1:1:22} <<

Comment: @Andres The entire text of that first code block can be saved to `books.awk`, and then you can run it from the command line like in the second code block (`awk -F: -f books.awk books`). It's a replacement for your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to read the entire thing into an array?   Query the file when you need information:

```
#!/bin/sh

# untested code:

# print the values of any line that match the pattern given in $1

grep "$1" BookDB.txt |
while IFS=: read  Title Author Price QtyAvailable QtySold; do
  echo title = $Title
  echo author = $Author
done
```

Unless your text file is very large, it is unlikely that you will need the data in an array.  If it is large enough that you need that for performance reasons, you really should not be coding this in sh.

Comment: This is what I would do. You can't read a table into an array, only a row, so it only makes sense to extract one row at a time from the file... at which point you may as well process it directly. Incidentally, though, you probably want a `while IFS=: read ... ; do ... done < <(grep ...)` construct so variables inside the `while` are part of the rest of the script.

Comment: this is my first time writing a program for it. so forgive me, the above chunk of codes, which part of it should i replace with? do i still need the cut function?

Comment: @Andres You do not need the cuts at all.  Using read with IFS=: does all of that work for you.

Comment: @sorpigal process substitution is a bashism which is sometimes handy, but the OP should be made aware that it is not portable.  (portability usually doesn't become a problem until *after* you've written tens of thousands of lines of code and find yourself debugging them for bashisms!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The question was for Linux, hence bash.